# How to delete duplicates from groups in R where group is formed by three columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, unique

Suppose we have a dataframe like this:

```
PatientID   BookingID   Level1   Level2  Value 
a1           101-A1        1     HBA1C   9.4
a2           102-A2        1     LDL     116
a1           101-A1        1     VLDL    11
a1           101-A1        2     POL     10
a1           102-A1        1     HBA1c   9.4
a2           102-A2        1     VLDL    10
a1           102-A1        1     VLDL    11
a2           103-A2        1     LDL     116
a2           103-A2        1     VLDL    11
a1           102-A1        2     POL     10
```

The idea is, a patient(Unique Patient ID) can come to lab and get tested for a set of conditions - broader category of test is level1, and their subcategories is level2(level1 has one to many relationship with level2), now the BookingId column for a patient ID can be different attributing to different dates of visits. value column represents values for each test(Patient ID has one to many relationship with BookingID).

So a group is formed by one combination of 'level1', 'patientID' and its 'Value', if the patientID **a1** came twice for getting himself tested - 101-A1 and 102-A1 and if all the test values are same, then only one of them remains, if there is any variation like in case of patientID **a2** then all the values remains, hence we want an o/p like this:

```
PatientID   BookingID   Level1   Level2  Value 
a1           101-A1        1     HBA1C    9.4
a2           102-A2        1      LDL     116
a1           101-A1        1      VLDL    11
a1           101-A1        2      POL     10
a2           102-A2        1      VLDL    10
a2           103-A2        1      LDL     116
a2           103-A2        1      VLDL    11
```

I tried using the following code from Dplyr package, but thats removing stuffs we want:

```
abcTest1 <- FullData %>% group_by(level1, patientId, value) %>% slice(1)
```

I cannot seem to do it correctly, please provide inputs

Comment: May I ask why you added the tags `mysql`, `excel`, and `sqlite` to your question?  This question doesn't seem relevant to any of those.  I might have gone for `unique`, `subset`, or `dataframe` instead.

Comment: @Barker I have the option of doing it on any tool, since sql syntax is supported by sqldf package

Comment: Take the trouble of having consistent col names, please. Anyway, the dplyr function for this is `DF %>% distinct(Level1, PatientID, Value)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do this:

```
library(dplyr)
> df
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   PatientID BookingID Level1 Level2 Value
       <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>  <chr> <dbl>
1         a1    101-A1      1  HBA1C   9.4
2         a2    102-A2      1    LDL 116.0
3         a1    101-A1      1   VLDL  11.0
4         a1    101-A1      2    POL  10.0
5         a1    102-A1      1  HBA1c   9.4
6         a2    102-A2      1   VLDL  10.0
7         a1    102-A1      1   VLDL  11.0
8         a2    103-A2      1    LDL 116.0
9         a2    103-A2      1   VLDL  11.0
10        a1    102-A1      2    POL  10.0
> df %>% distinct(PatientID, Level1, Value, .keep_all=TRUE)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  PatientID BookingID Level1 Level2 Value
      <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>  <chr> <dbl>
1        a1    101-A1      1  HBA1C   9.4
2        a2    102-A2      1    LDL 116.0
3        a1    101-A1      1   VLDL  11.0
4        a1    101-A1      2    POL  10.0
5        a2    102-A2      1   VLDL  10.0
6        a2    103-A2      1   VLDL  11.0
```

As with @Barker's answer, this doesn't include that last `116.0` row, but that's because your logic doesn't hold. You state that "if the patientID a1 came twice for getting himself tested - 101-A1 and 102-A1 and if all the test values are same, then only one of them remains", which we see in rows 1 and 5, and in your expected out put only row 1 remains. However, the exact same logic holds for rows 2 and 8, yet you want to keep both rows.

### New Answer Based on Comments

Okay, I finally understand what you're saying and have been able to decipher the rules needed to properly deduplicate. It's a convoluted process, but would look like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(PatientID, BookingID) %>% 
  mutate(Key = paste(Level1, Level2, Value, collapse=";")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-Level1, -Level2, -Value) %>% 
  distinct(PatientID, Key, .keep_all=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Key = str_split(Key, ";")) %>% 
  unnest(Key) %>% 
  separate(Key, into=c("Level1", "Level2", "Value"), 
           sep=" ", remove=TRUE) %>%
  arrange(PatientID, BookingID, Level1, Level2)

# A tibble: 7 × 5
  PatientID BookingID Level1 Level2 Value
*     <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1        a1    101-A1      1  HBA1C   9.4
2        a1    101-A1      1   VLDL    11
3        a1    101-A1      2    POL    10
4        a2    102-A2      1    LDL   116
5        a2    102-A2      1   VLDL    10
6        a2    103-A2      1    LDL   116
7        a2    103-A2      1   VLDL    11
```

Basically, we start out by taking the three values that are of most interest to us, `Level1`, `Level2`, and `Value`, and putting into a string where we separate each set of values for each `BookingID` by a semicolon. This will give us two rows of information for both `PatientID == a1` and `PatientID == a2`, for four rows total. We then deduplicate by only `PatientID` and `Key`, but tell R to keep `BookingID` as well. What we find is that the data is identical for `a1`, but is different for `a2` because `Value` where `Level2 == POL` is not the same on both visits. So after we deduplicate, we're left with three rows. We then split `Key` using the semicolon as the separator, and then `separate` the `Key` variable to get our original columns back.

Comment: think of level1 as broad category, such as electronics on amazon - which has products like laptops, phones(level2),  - say for level1 there are 50 level2 tests, then for one patientID, there will be repeating 50 bookingIds - and each having its value in 'value' column. 
So if a patient comes thrice, there will be 3 bookingID repeated 50 times each, we need to compare group of 50 values against other two group of 50 values. Only when we find that all 50 values in one group match in other two groups, we delete. Else even one variation and all value remains

Comment: value of bookingID changes with different visits for a single patientId. what you have suggested as an answer was what I thought of in very first instance, but this leads to unnecessary deletions. Please check the code I have pasted

Comment: So because 101-A1 contains the three values "HBA1C", "LDL", and "POL", as does 102-A1, we can delete all values of 102-A1? That logic still doesn't hold up with the data. Until you can clearly describe the rules behind deduicating, I don't think anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: don't think of it as like that - for a particular patientId  a1 - there are two bookingId - 101-A1 and 102-A1,  if all related values for 101-A1, which is test values for HBA1C, LDL and POL, if they match with all the values in the second bookingID 102-A1, which it does here than we retain only the first bookingId values for a particular patient.

Comment: @Rohan I've updated my answer, which should get you what you need.

Comment: just to bum a few bits off your code you can `summarise` in lieu of the first `mutate` and (de)`select`, and no need for parentheses in the `ungroup` or even `distinct` as the raw defaults (empirically and according to the documentation) get you the same activity as you are argumenting. The residual ordering from the summary even lets you drop the final arrange.

Comment: like so `df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(PatientID, BookingID) %>% 
    summarise(Key = paste(Level1, Level2, Value, collapse = ":")) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    distinct %>% 
    mutate(Key = str_split(Key, ":")) %>% 
    unnest(Key) %>% 
    separate(Key, into = c("Level1", "Level2", "Value"), sep = " ")`

Comment: @leerssej I personally am a proponent for leaving the parentheses on functions even if there are no parameters;  I think it makes the code cleaner. But you're right, using `summarize` would remove the need for a couple function calls, which can save time on large datasets.

Comment: @brittenb you mean, value of POL gets repeated hence we retain only one value right? Otherwise this looks good

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic use for the `duplicated()` function.  This function determines the unique elements of a vector or data frame and returns a logical indicating which elements have been seen earlier in the object.  In this case, we can use `duplicated()` on the columns of the data frame that you want to find the unique elements of and use the output to index.

```
> df[!duplicated(df[c("PatientID", "Level1", "Value")]), ]
  PatientID BookingID Level1 Level2 Value
1        a1    101-A1      1  HBA1C   9.4
2        a2    102-A2      1    LDL 116.0
3        a1    101-A1      1   VLDL  11.0
4        a1    101-A1      2    POL  10.0
6        a2    102-A2      1   VLDL  10.0
9        a2    103-A2      1   VLDL  11.0
```

My output is slightly different than yours as the second row with value `116` is not there, but based on your description, I believe that was an error in the example.

Comment: please understand the question correctly - patientID a2 has one different value for vldl in last column '11', hence all other values for a particular level1 for that patientID needs to remain the same, hence second row with value 116 is needed

Comment: @Rohan what you want is; if all unique combinations of `PatientID` and `Level1` have the same `Value`, return unique values of `PatientID` and `Level1`; else return all data for that `PatientID` ?

Comment: yes the idea is if a patient comes and gets himself tested for a level1 test thrice - and say level1 has 20 different tests(shown by level2), so if in all 20*3 entries, value of first 20 is repeated across 3 times, then we take unique values, else even if there is one mismatch, we leave all the info as it is

Comment: Problem with such a step is, if there is a very large dataset ...then it may happen that even though level1 values for entire level2 test may differ - but if some level2 values are same, those will be eliminated - though they will come under same level1

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do in a simple manner using the excellent [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) package:

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
FullData %<>% as.data.table

abcTest1 <- FullData %>% unique(by = c("level1", "patientId", "value"))
```

Comment: Whoops, add library(magrittr)

Comment: abcTest1 <- final1 %>% unique(by = ("level1", "patientId", "value"))
Error: unexpected ',' in "abcTest1 <- final1 %>% unique(by = ("level1","

Comment: Hey Andrew, can you please explain the difference between your code and mine:
abcTest1 <- FullData %>% unique(by = c("level1", "patientId", "value"))
abcTest1 <- FullData %>% group_by(level1, patientId, value) %>% slice(1)

Comment: I checked my code gets the same output as yours I do not think there is a difference

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply using unique

```
PatientID <- c("a1","a2","a1")
BookingID <- c("num1","num2","num1")
Level1 <- c(1,2,1)
Level2 <- c("HBA", "CDA", "HBA")
Value <- c(10,4,10)

df <- data.frame(PatientID,BookingID,Level1,Level2,Value)
df <- unique(df)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because `unique()` will look at all the columns and the `BookingID` and `Level2` columns will cause problems.

Comment: Barker, but the question demands that it should be unique across all columns, doesn't it?

Comment: Barker, what kind of problems will it cause, can you run my code once and check, it's reporducible

Comment: According to the asker *" a group is formed by one combination of 'level1', 'patientID' and its 'Value', if the patientID a1 came twice for getting himself tested - 101-A1 and 102-A1 and if all the test values are same, then only one of them remains"*, so only `Level1`, `PatientID`, and `Value` matter, not `BookingID` or `Level2`.  Your example only works because you are using it on different data.  I ran it on the asker's data and nothing was removed.  You can use `read.table(text = "copyAndPasteTextHere", header = TRUE)` to easily read in their data.

Comment: @Barker can you suggest something else please